# Wicket inheritance issue

Tags: java, inheritance, wicket

I'm developing a Wicket application for college and I ran into (a somewhat tricky) problem.

To put some context: I'm making an application that uses a HTML5 player, my solution to this was to give the constructor of the page that contains the player some `PageParamameters` to make a query and retrieve the sources for the media.

Now my problem is that I'm using a template, so I made a page that puts the Header and the footer automatically, but my player needs the `PageParameters` to work and I'm trying to make it so it can extend from `BasePage`, but the constructor from base page also has some parameters so it can dynamically change the text on the header based on the page it is currently on. This makes putting the `super()` method tricky:

```
protected BasePage(String tabHeader, String header) {
    add(new Label("tab_title", tabHeader));
    add(new Header("header", header));
    add(new UserPanel("user_panel"));
    add(new Footer("footer"));
}
```

And my player page:

```
public PlayerPage(PageParameters params) {
    String name = params.get("name").toString();
    MediaItem item = getItem(name.trim());

    add(new Label("tab_title", "MaeGûl - " + name)); //trying to get rid of this
    add(new Header("header", item.getName())); //and this
    add(new UserPanel("user_panel")); //and this

    if (item.getType().equals(ItemTypes.MUSIC)) {
        add(new AudioPlayer("player", item.getMediaSources()));
    } else if (item.getType().equals(ItemTypes.SERIES)
            || item.getType().equals(ItemTypes.MOVIES))
        add(new VideoPlayer("player", item.getMediaSources()));

    add(new Footer("footer")); //and this
}
```

As you may see, if I put the `super(tabHeader, header)` in my `PlayerPage` constructor it needs the "name" parameter to update the header and tabHeader of the `BasePage`, so I'm stupmed...

Any solutions to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may change the `BasePage` to accept models instead of strings:

```
protected BasePage(IModel<String> tabHeader, IModel<String> header)
```

and delegate the retrieval of the values to dedicated models, e.g. derived from `AbstractReadOnlyModel`:

```
public PlayerPage(PageParameters params) {
    super(new TabHeaderModel(params), new HeaderModel(params));
    ...
}
```

Comment: +1. This is good advice. Although it could be also considered to drop the constructor args and pull them from an overridable `protected IModel getTabHeaderModel()`.

Comment: thanks I will try to make this, and if it works I'll post the solution for someone with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is, of course, a method that can be used by any component to get the `PageParameters`.  It is..

```
getPage().getPageParameters();
```

For `getPageParameters()` to return a non-null value, however, you must have called the Wicket `Page` constructor with `super(params)`, therefore insisting that your `BasePage` have a constructor `BasePage(PageParameters params)`.

In fact, after playing around with this for awhile, if you use `BookmarkablePageLink` and `PageParameters` for most of your pages, then anything extending `Page` should only implement the constructor `Page(PageParameters params)`.  This doesn't apply if you use session relative pages and a lot of `new PlayerPage()` type of code.